# Reg. how to find the local timezone with UTC and Local time in java

Tags: java, jsp, date, datetime

I have a flat file(application log) which contain UTC and Local time, But i am in need to find the local timezone(From where that file actually created/generated).

For your reference, Time snippet from the file

```
UTC time  : 2015-05-29T06:25:30.840

Local time: 2015-05-29T08:25:30.840
```

Could you please let me know your thoughts/ideas.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218542/get-correct-local-time-in-java-calendar
Moreover, you could try to deduce local timezone from the shift between itself and UTC

Comment: What @pnadczuk said is probably the only way. However you could end up with multiple answers... For example you could be seeing somewhere with a Daylight Saving Time enable or somewhere in another time zone without DST.

Comment: @Dennis of course, you are not able to guess somebody's location from the timezone, but you have the timezone. Let's consider UK - you can either be in GMT or in BST. So after you calculate the shift, you know which one is it.

Comment: @pnadczuk  and Dennis - Thanks for your response.. As i mentioned above my problem here is, the only way to find the timezone is with two strings(local and UTC time)..so is there any way to find with these two strings..? i think there is no use to calcaulate with system local time zone or locale. since i need to find the timezone of the log file(Where it is actually created)

Comment: @pnadczuk Yes of course I forgot that he had the date as well !